# Convergence along the diagonal

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Let $\ell_n \to \ell$ in $X^*$ and $(x_n)$ be a weakly convergent sequence in $X$. Show that $\ell_n(x_n) \to \ell(x)$.

We then have that

$$\ell_1(x_n) \to \ell_1(x)$$
$$\ell_2(x_n) \to \ell_2(x)$$
$$\ell_3(x_n) \to \ell_3(x)$$
$$\vdots$$

I have a hard time approaching this problem, and even worse a hard time seeing why it reasonably should be true. I know that $\|\ell_n\| \to \|\ell \|$ but I can't really get started. Is there a good approach in general to this kind of "diagonal" problem?

Comment: Also, I want to add that $\ell_n \to \ell$ means $\|\ell_n - \ell\| \to 0$. You get what you said, $\|\ell_n \| \to \|\ell\|$ from the reverse triangle inequality. But the other direction is not true: $\|\ell_n\| \to \|\ell\|$ does NOT imply $\|\ell_n - \ell\| \to 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

$|\ell_n(x_n) - \ell(x)| \le |\ell_n(x_n) -\ell_n(x_m)| + |\ell_n(x_m) - \ell (x_m)| + |\ell(x_m) - \ell(x)|$.

Now, since $\ell_n$ and $\ell$ are functionals in $X^*$, the outer two quantities can be made arbitrarily small, since $\{\ell_n(x_m)\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent and thus Cauchy, and $\{\ell(x_m)\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $\ell(x)$ by weak convergence.

To take care of the middle term, we have $|\ell_n(x_m) - \ell (x_m)|\le \|\ell_n - \ell\|\|x_m\|$ and this can be made arbitrarily small since $\ell_n \to \ell$ by hypothesis.